# Finding first empty cell in a row problem

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to clear everything in each sheet starting from the first empty cell in the 10th row (Microsoft Excel) but .End property skip the empty cell between filled ones.

I tried such code:

```
Sub clearRange()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As Long, i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count - 1
        Set ws = Worksheets(i)
        lastColumn = ws.Cells(10, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(10, lastColumn + 1), ws.Range("CZ200000")).ClearContents
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Cell D10 is skipped:
[Sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYoDg.png)

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
lastColumn = ws.Cells(10, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

will take you to column J as the last column in your picture (`lastColumn = 10`), NOT to column D.

To find the first empty cell, start in column A and use end-right, **if A10:B10 are both non-empty**. If either can be empty, you'll have to address them individually.

```
Sub clearRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As Long, i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count - 1
        Set ws = Worksheets(i)
        lastColumn = ws.Cells(10, 1).End(xlToRight).Column + 1  ' Do this
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(10, lastColumn + 1), ws.Range("CZ200000")).ClearContents
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

If this does or doesn't work for you, let us know the result.

And in future requests, please include a table we can copy. We can't copy a screenshot to a worksheet.